# BATCH GENERATE QR USING VCARD METADATA

Tags: excel, csv, adobe-indesign, vcf-vcard

I want to create QR from vcard metadata and recently I found video that explains batch create multiple QR at once (https://youtu.be/t7xV1DXNM8Y?t=793). But in the tutorial he doesn't explains how he generated vcard metaddata in to one line. I have a excel sheet that contains data and I want to converted them into vcard metadata.

When I'm converted the excel data in to vcard I get below output. (Figure 1)

[image: Figure 1 - vCard Standard Format]

Is it possible to get above output into one line (Figure 2)

[image: Figure 2 - Needed Format]

I want to automate these process and is there any detailed guide to this.

If there's any alternative way to do this point them out.

Comment: Have you tried just stringing it all together using a formula?  Can you show your data spreadsheet?  Are you expecting this to be done in Excel or is Excel just the source?

Comment: I'm using indesign data merge to generate qr and excel as a source. can i do this using CONCAT function. Currently I don't have any idea to use that function and I'm linking a preview of excel fields to this https://imgur.com/IzS2jM8

Comment: Ok, so using Excel as an engine to do what you want is pretty much out of the question then, correct?  IF so, I suggest taking the Excel tag off the question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use the Excel formula [TEXTJOIN()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)

Something about this:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",true,"BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:",A1,"\nN:",B1,"\nORG:",C1,"\nEND:VCARD")
```